# Form not posting variables/mySQL Query not searching corrently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a player edit system for an admin section of a football website.
The process goes as follows:

Once a coach has logged in on 'coaches.php', they can then choose what coaching session they want to look at via dropdown, which then populates the 'player' dropdown (done via js below)

**coaches.php form**

```
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="coachplayer.php?id=' .$id. '">
            <label>Activity :</label>
            <select name="activity" class="activity">
                <option selected="selected">--Select Activity Group--</option>
                    <?php
                    include('dbconnect.php');
                    $sql=mysql_query("select activity from coaches where username='$coach'");
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                      {
                          $activity2=explode(",",$row["activity"]);
                          foreach ($activity2 as $activity)
                         echo '<option value="'.$activity.'">'.$activity.'</option>';
                     } ?>
                </select> <br/><br/>
                <label>Player :</label> <select name="username" class="username">
                <option selected="selected">--Select Player--</option>

            </select>
            <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />

        </form>
```

**coaches.php js function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".activity").change(function()
{
var activity=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'activity='+ activity;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_city.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".username").html(html);
} 
});

});
});
</script>
<style>
label
{
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
```

As the js above shows, the player list is handled via a separate page with a query on it as follows:

```
<?php
if($_POST['activity'])
{
$activity=$_POST['activity'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM stats WHERE activity='$activity'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$username=$row['username'];
$activity=$row['activity'];
echo '<option value="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</option>';

}
}

?>
```

Once all of this is done, the coach submits the form, taking them to coachplayer.php. This is where the problem begins.

coachplayer.php is a template page, with empty fields filled with echo's, to echo the player details where necessary. A query runs to get the id of the selected player, bring up their details and fill the page. Instead, however, it echos what usually comes up if the query cannot find a matching result via $playerCount as shown below, saying "Player doesn't exist".

**coachplayer.php SQL query**

```
<?php 
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    $targetU = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    // Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the player 
    // details, if no then exit this script and give message why
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id='$targetU' LIMIT 1");
    $playerCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($playerCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $username = $row["username"];
             $position = $row["position"];
             $activity = $row["activity"];
             $agegroup = $row["agegroup"];
             $coach = $row["coach"];
             $goals = $row["goals"];
             $assists = $row["assists"];
             $cleans = $row["cleans"];
             $motm = $row["motm"];
             $attend = $row["attend"];
         }

    } else {
        echo "Player doesn't exist.";
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
    exit();
}
?>
```

As I'm sure you can tell, I'm not too great of a coder, so it's very possible that it's a simply var that needs changing but any ideas where I have gone wrong will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Echo $targetU prior executing query just to make sure you are passing correct ID.

Comment: @sskoko I put in echo $targetU the line after     $targetU = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);  but the page still just shows "Player doesn't exist".

Comment: It looks like your $targetU is blank after preg_replace.

Comment: @sskoko What do you mean by this? I thought it's being called and associated to being the id and is then looked for via the query?

Comment: There is a secret ancient technique called debugging. First determine the line that does not work as expected, Then determine which part of it is not what you think it should be, in this case there is only one part that is unknown : $targetU. Check it's value, if it's not what it should be, check the line that assigns $targetU... repeat from the beginning... The other ancient wisdom is to use tools - online regex testers for debugging regex expressions, visual sql tools like MySql Workbench for making sure that your queries are good. things like this will make you a better programmer

Comment: @Konstantin thanks for your adivce - I've tried to 'reverse-program' my way through this but everytime I check what came before it - to me at least - everything seems to be making sense so now I'm just stuck

Comment: Let's try it again: what is the problem - what is the line that does not do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @Konstantin that would be the line defining targetU as its apparently coming up as blank.

Comment: @sskoko you mentioned that $targetU becomes blank after preg_replace, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @JioFreed google 'php preg_replace online' and go play with it.

Comment: @Konstantin that comment was somewhat condescending, and the result of which, does not answer this question. id is a number, the current preg replace removes anything but numbers and leave it blank.

Comment: @Konstantin I'm using the ID 'A6', though even when i changed it to just 6, the id was still empty, though the comments in indra's answer helped specify what the issue was, but no idea how to fix it yet

Comment: @JioFreed So what is the problem: preg_replace() or missing/empty $_REQUEST['id']?

Comment: @Konstantin has to be missing/empty ID

Comment: So the problem is not in PHP but in JS. right? Learn to use DevTools or Firebug

Answer (score 1):

You are using a form with post method. And the action URL seems quite different

```
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="coachplayer.php?id=' .$id. '">
```

Change it to

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="coachplayer.php">
```

and in coachplayer.php. Use

```
    isset($_POST['thisID']
```

Comment: Okay, so what should I be doing then?

Comment: Somehow $_GET['id'] is set, otherwise he would receive: "Data to render this page is missing."

Comment: After changing action URL and isset....... Try to echo the $targetU and see whether you are passing the right id

Comment: hi @IndraKumarS I made your changes and then changed the 'Player doesn't exist' output to echo $targetU; but the page just comes up blank, doesn't echo an ID

Comment: echo before your query.

Comment: @IndraKumarS still blank

Comment: Can you check your form input thisID's Value

Comment: @IndraKumarS            <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

Comment: Change the type to text to see what is echoed by echo $id

Comment: @IndraKumarS i do believe we've found problem zero - this comes up as blank which would suggest its not pulling the id from the JS

Comment: @IndraKumarS this has helped me identify it but I have no idea how to rectify this. I have just above basic-level knowledge with JS, and id is being called in the same place as username (which shows) i've even juggled around by making it: echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$username.'</option>';
 but it still comes up blank. Any idea what has gone wrong here?

Comment: sorry @IndraKumarS i forgot to tag you before, it's in the second and third code blocks of the original post

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I admit this is not an answer to your question BUT, to be honest there is no such thing as 'your question' - there are contents of four files each of them with their own problems, and an implicit request to grock all of those 4 files and tell you what does not work and how it should be made to work.

Having said that:

- Divide and conquer. Make sure your first script does exactly what needs to be done. Then second, then 3rd and only then 4th.
- Use tools: For javascript - Dev Tools or Firebug. For queries - MySQL Workbench
  When testing JS use console (here you can try out your js code interactively.
  ) and source tabs - there you can set breakpoints and follow execution line by line. Look at network tab - there you can see request (headers) and responses. 
  When debugging PHP comment out all your code and use var_dump every step of the way. I use PHP Storm so that i can debug PHP line by line real time.

And better ask questions that can be described with the least lines of code

PS. You can simulate GET requests by typing url in browser - that way you know whether your server side works or not without relying on unreliable JS

Answer (score -1):

Just a Quick look, but your sql Statement seems wrong. Your sql query will search for the Player with the id '$targetU'. Make sure to enter the variable correctly